# In fragment replace find which fragment was there previously

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there method to find which fragment call current fragment?

```
Frag A -> Frag C

Frag B -> Frag C
```

So I need to find which fragment called fragment C.

Fragment change method

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment, Bundle args, String tag){
        resideMenu.clearIgnoredViewList();
        if(args != null)
            targetFragment.setArguments(args);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, tag)
                .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code before replacing fragment:

```
 Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
 if( currentFragment instanceof A) {
    // currentFragment is A;
 } else if( currentFragment instanceof B) {
    // currentFragment is B;
 }
```

> [public abstract Fragment findFragmentById (int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int))
>
> Finds a fragment that was identified by the given id either when
>   inflated from XML or as the container ID when added in a transaction.
>   This first searches through fragments that are currently added to the
>   manager's activity; if no such fragment is found, then all fragments
>   currently on the back stack associated with this ID are searched.

Comment: I can't understand why?

Comment: From your question what i understood is you need to find previous fragment when you switch to fragment C? is it right?

Comment: previous fragment find by id wont work. because it can be any from A or B

Comment: Yeh thats why "instance of" will help you to find whether its from A or B.

Comment: Well yes. But how to find the id of the previous fragment. That can be id_of_A or id_of_B

Comment: I mean how to find id of previous fragment

Comment: Can you please tell me what is use of id_of_A or id_of_B in your code? are you taking about tag?

Comment: You are taking R.id.main_fragment in first line. So in my case I can't tell exactly its main_fragment. It can be A or B

Comment: Ohh man.. you may not need to know the fragment id.  Here  R.id.main_fragment is the id of the fragment holder(it can be FrameLayout); it will be same for all fragment. you need to put fragment in that fragment holder. that you are already doing i guess.

Comment: Please take a look on [this](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-fragment-transaction.html).